# tablesorter + bootstrap = no icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tablesorter

I'm using this fork:http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#Support

and my code is:

```
$(".records_list").tablesorter(
        {
            theme : 'bootstrap',
            widgets: ["zebra","uitheme"],
            headerTemplate : '{content} {icon}', 
            widgetOptions : {
              zebra : [ "even", "odd" ]
            }
      }
);
```

What it's the problem?

if generates the following html:

```
<div class="tablesorter-header-inner">Abbreviation <i class="tablesorter-icon"></i></div>
```

but, I think that it should have some of theses classes: .tablesorter-bootstrap .bootstrap-icon-unsorted or .tablesorter-bootstrap .icon-white.bootstrap-icon-unsorted

:(

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing the [theme.bootstrap.css](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/css/theme.bootstrap.css) file and/or the Bootstrap 3+ css file.

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way I've found to fix this is to edit your BundleConfig to add jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js to wherever you are calling the tablesorter.js.

E.g.,

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tablesorter").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.js",
                    "~/Scripts/TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js"));
```